# Regex statement to validate a string is exactly 2 lines

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm looking for a regex statement to verify a string is exactly 2 lines. I'm using the [.Net regex syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx).

I want to make sure that the whole input string is included. I assume I'll need the `\A` and `\Z` markers at the start and end of my expression. I'm also using the [Unicode line boundaries](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Line_Boundaries) of `(\r\n|[\n\v\f\r\x85\u2028\u2029])`.

So far I have created the follow. Although it does not work as expected.

```
\A.+?(\r\n|[\n\v\f\r\x85\u2028\u2029])[^\n\v\f\r\x85\u2028\u2029]+?\1?\Z
```

***Example input***

*Match*

```
some line
other line
```

*No match*

```
some line
other line
this is incorrect input
```

The line can have an optional new line character after the last line. As long as it doesn't have any text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^[^\r\n]+\r\n[^\r\n]+$

^ - start of string
[^\r\n]+ - any character that isn't a CRLF (New line) (1 or more times)
\r\n - match a CRLF (new line)
[^\r\n]+ - same as before
$ - end of string
```

just read your last bit, you can have optional new line at the end with

```
^[^\r\n]+\r\n[^\r\n]+(\r\n)?$
```

Comment: Your solution is very close to what I went with. I changed `\r\n` with the more generic `(\r\n|[\n\v\f\r\x85\u2028\u2029])`. I also used `\A` and `\Z` instead of `^` and `$` because I want to check at the start end end of the whole string. Final regex is `\A[^\n\v\f\r\x85\u2028\u2029]+?(\r\n|[\n\v\f\r\x85\u2028\u2029])[^\n\v\f\r\x85\u2028\u2029]+?\1?\Z` using the single line option.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to play with your regex options, but ultimately your regex should look like this

`@"^[^\n]*\n[^\n]*\n*$"`

the `\n*` at the end is your optional newlines